# Full resolution saving in iPhone

Tags: ios, image, graphics

I'm trying to create an iPhone app that allows user to do some photo editing, like texturing, distorting or filtering images.

The app works fine when I use images scaled down to 320x460 (or some such resolution). But I'd like to give the user the freedom to save the image in full resolution.

Can you please let me know the best method for implementing such a mechanism.

(My initial plan is to keep a log of all actions of the user in a XML and then apply all of them to the original image in disk on clicking an apply/save button. But with multiple distortions and textures, keeping track of everything is being a nightmare).

Can someone let me know the usual method for doing this.

P.S: I've tried interpolating the 320x460 to original size using apple's library, but the results are far from satisfactory for larger images